# Business intelligence Template for visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting, business-intelligence

I have visual studio 2010 installed and using the TFS. I can't open the reports as I dont have the BI templates installed.

I just want to know how do I install the templates if possible?

Comment: Are you trying to open a report in VS2010? If you are using SQL Server 2008 or lower you will need Visual Studio 2008 that comes with sql server (you can just install the tools I believe) or the Report Designer.

Comment: On this computer I have visual studio 2008 and 2010 (2008 can open the reports). I also have SQL 2005, 2008, 2008r2 and 2012. and yes i'm trying to open up a report but I will also like to create a bran new report using the 2010 template

Comment: I don't believe the reports can be opened from within 2010. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767%28v=sql.105%29.aspx